# Why I got "Unreachable Statement Error" for the fragment?

Tags: java, android, fragment

```
/**
 * Created by myozawoo on 3/12/16.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Bind(R.id.home_screen_toolbar) Toolbar toolbar;

    private FragmentDrawer fragmentDrawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);



        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        fragmentDrawer = (FragmentDrawer) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        fragmentDrawer.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);
        fragmentDrawer.setDrawerListener(this);

        displayView(0);


    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {

        displayView(position);

    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new SearchDonorsFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.nav_item_search_donors);
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.nav_item_profile);
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new AboutFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.nav_item_about);
                break;
            default:
                break;

            if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

                // set the toolbar title
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
            }

        }
    }


}
```

My Activity was extended to AppCompatActivity. I have successfully setup a drawer too. Now when i do transaction on Fragment basically it uses begintransaction. but i got this error message Unreachable statement on `FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();`. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: what do you think will happen after the `default` `break` statement?

Comment: no idea... coz... displayView(0);

Comment: how should I do bro?

Comment: after break your compiler will exit switch case and your transaction code will never get called in any case

Answer (score 2):

This segment of the code..

```
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = ....
        }
```

is never executed, because is not associated with any case in the switch condition...

That is the reason of the error.

## Qhick fix:

you can:

1-. move that out of the switch case

or

2-. think in which of the cases should be executed.

Comment: 1 is okay for me bro... I forgot to move out of the switch case :D

Comment: then you found the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to rethink the logic of your switch statement. A `break` statement terminates the switch statement, and no code after it runs, so a `break` should be after any code that could potentially run.

Answer (score 0):

Give `break` after code on default section. **code is not reachable because it is given break first on default position**. So change your default section as below:

```
        default:
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            // set the toolbar title
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

`default` in a `case` control flow means that if any of the other options did not workout, `default` will be called.

If you put a `break` into it, what follows will def. be unreachable.

Looking at the logic of your code, the `if` should be place outside of the `switch`

```
switch(position){
    // cases
    default : break;
}

if (fragment != null) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    // set the toolbar title
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
```